# Unable to store in database while using Laravel (version 7.25)

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I am trying to get hold of Laravel framework and got stuck while retrieving the values from the page in a Database.

These are the snippets of my controller, routes, view part which might help in understanding what I am doing

web.php (for routes):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Postcontroller.php (just a snippet)

```
<?php
public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('posts.create');
    }

       public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request , array(
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ));
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->body = $request->body;

        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
    }
```

create.blade.php(for view)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-mid-8 col-md-offset-2" >
        <h1>Create New Post</h1>
        <hr>
        <form route='posts.store' >
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inputs need `name` attributes to be passed on. There are no inputs with any names, let alone anything labeled `title` or `body`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you don't have `name` properties on your input, so nothing gets passed to your backend code.

Add name to your inputs like this (they need to be different, else they would get overwritten):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="your-unique-input-id" name"your_unique_input_name">
```

Then, when you submit your form, the all the inputs that have `name` attribute in them will get passed to your backend method. You can then retrieve their value, by using the `name` you gave them earlier. So in this example:

```
$request->your_unique_input_name // Which will return anything that user typed in that field
```